# Passing javascript var to PHP through url

Tags: php, javascript, get, gd

I have two javascript variables var 1 and var 2 which I need to pass to PHP through GET method.

```
$('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1=var1&econdIcon=var2 />');
```

In my .php file, I merge two icons using GD PHP and send the image back using imagepng.

```
$firstIcon = $_GET['icon1'];   
$secondIcon = $_GET['icon2'];  

// Process images

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
```

When I pass the direct image path and dont use the var1 and var 2 it works fine, but with var1 and var 2 it doesnt work. What could be the problem?

Comment: see the `src` value in the firebug most probably it is still `var1` and `var2` and not the value you want.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the variables, what exactly fails where?

Comment: Can we have concret exemple of the content of ```$firstIcon``` and ```$secondIcon``` ? Notice the mispelling in your first code. Think also about [urldecode()](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) if necessary.

Comment: See error logs, I think it will have notice: undefined index 'icon2' as you use `econdIcon` instead in `src`.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your `img src`. you have `icon1=var1&econdIcon=var2`. Why isn't this `secondIcon`?

Comment: My mistake, its actually $('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1=var1&icon2=var2 />');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are sending var1 and var2 to PHP as strings. They need to be sent as variables...

```
$('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1='+var1+'&econdIcon='+var2+'" />');
```

Comment: This doesnt work, It does not append the div "output_images" with the img tag. Nothing is added.

Answer (score 2):

Are you simply not concatentating the values correctly.  If you don;t want literal `var1` and `var2` perhaps try this:

```
$('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1='+var1+'&econdIcon='+var2+'" />');
```

You also need to make sure your parameter names match in javascript and PHP (they don't for `icon2` right now)

Comment: The values of Var1 and Var2 are actually the image path. For Example, Var1 = Images/abc.png and Var2 = Images/xyz.png. If I directly pass the image paths it works, but not when I pass the variables. Looks like, the var value is not getting passed but variable name is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you copy and pasted it, I do see a typo in the url, **&econdIcon=var2**, might need to be &icon2=var2

Also Mike Brant is right they need to be concatenated.